# How should Selection selectfinish/selectend event be implemented?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, observable, dom-events, textselection

I'm looking to do something whenever a user finishes making a selection —essentially, on the first `mouseup` event after every [`selectstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectstart) event, I think— on the page. I want to take that selection and wrap it in an element to be styled via CSS. I presumed the Selection API offered an event for this; however, it doesn't seem to.

I don't simply listen for `mouseup` 'cause I'm especially looking for this to work with the selection that results from the browser's find functionality ("Find in This Page…"; <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>).

```js
let selContainer = document.createElement('span')
span.classList.add('user-selection')

const wrapSelection = () => {
  window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).surroundContent(selContainer)
}


/*                   ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
                     ┃                          ┃
                     ┃  The Selection API only  ┃
                     ┃  affords these events:   ┃
                     ┃                          ┃
                     ┃  - selectionchange       ┃
                     ┃  - selectstart     ┏━━━━━┫
                     ┃                    ┃issue┃
                     ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━┛

*/document.addEventListener('selectfinish', wrapSelection)/*
                             ┗━━━━┳━━━━━┛
                                  ┃
                                  ┃
                               no such
                                event                                                                                                                                                                                                        */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that I've gotten it to work is to track the `selectionchange` event and when the selection doesn't change for over 500ms, I consider that a select end. It's not perfect, but it works and correctly triggers for any kind of selection, be it mouse, keyboard, or CTRL+F.

```
    let selectionDelay = null, selection = '';

    document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
        const currentSelection = document.getSelection().toString();
        if (currentSelection != selection) {
            selection = currentSelection;
            if (selectionDelay) {
                window.clearTimeout(selectionDelay);
            }
            selectionDelay = window.setTimeout(() => {
                wrapSelection();
                selection = '';
                selectionDelay = null;
            }, 500);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

This is trickier than it should be. I’ve used a combination of `element.onselectstart`, `element.onmouseup`, and `document.onselectionchange`. Take a look at this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jmakeig/hscabpe3/).

```
function onSelect(element, callback) {
    // console.log(element, callback);
    let isSelecting = false;
    let selection = null;

    function handleSelectStart(event) {
        // console.log(event);
        isSelecting = true; 
    }

    function handleMouseUp(event) {
        // console.log(event, isSelecting);
        if (isSelecting && !document.getSelection().isCollapsed) {
            callback((selection = document.getSelection()));
            isSelecting = false;
        }
    }

    function handleSelectionChange(event) {
        // console.log('change', isSelecting);
        if (document.getSelection().isCollapsed && null !== selection) {
            callback((selection = null));
        }
    }

    element.addEventListener('selectstart', handleSelectStart);
    element.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    document.addEventListener('selectionchange', handleSelectionChange);

    return function destroy() {
        element.removeEventListener('selectstart', handleSelectStart);
        element.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
        document.removeEventListener('selectionchange', handleSelectionChange);
    };
}
```

This won’t handle non-mouse interactions. Accommodating pointer and keyboard events would be a nice enhancement. I think the overall pattern holds, though.

Answer (score 1):

I picked through the [source code](https://github.com/hypothesis/client) of the [hypothes.is](https://hypothes.is) web annotation client in an effort to understand how they get their `toolbar` to appear on user select action *end*. It seems to be a matter of [employing an observer](https://github.com/hypothesis/client/blob/81a008260ecd3ac1f506c34c64d613386f139489/src/annotator/selections.js) via [zen-observable](https://github.com/hypothesis/client/blob/81a008260ecd3ac1f506c34c64d613386f139489/src/annotator/util/observable.js#L8).

Comment: Is their solution the best/simplest/only one? If so, how exactly does it work, is it setup; if not, what else is there?

Answer (score 0):

simpler alternative to the accepted answer.

```
 document.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
     var s = document.getSelection();
     if (!s.isCollapsed) {
          // do sth with selection
     }
 });
```

or maybe better?

```
 document.addEventListener('selectstart', e => {
     document.addEventListener('mouseup', somefunction);
 });
 function somefunction(e) {
     // do sth
     document.removeEventListener('mouseup', somefunction);
 }
```

Comment: What about when a selection is made without leveraging the mouse, e.g., when the user uses Find?